# How to obtain the below effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Desired Output:

[image]

Output Obtained:

[image]

**How to get the desired output as per 1st image?**

MyLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/tvQty"
        android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
        android:text="x1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvFoodName"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Ceaser Salad with Herb Grilled Chicken Ceaser Ceaser Salad with Herb "
        android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvFoodPrice"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="1234"
        android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

What is my problem?
Other than TableLayout, is there anyother option to get desired result?
Should I calculate the width for each TextView and set it from code?

Comment: `width="wrap_content"` tells the UI to ignore weights for width. Try `width="0dp"` instead.

Comment: Thanks @StenSoft that really helped.Plus i never new of this wrap content   and weigths logit..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Table Layout

This type of layouts could be easily achieved using a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm

In your case, you would need a table with 3 rows and 3 columns.

---

### Linear Layout

Also you can lay out your views like that picture using two types of [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)s.

- One container LinearLayout with vertical orientation.
- Multiple LinearLayout acting like rows with horizontal orientation.

Each row should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Issue was the weidth was wrap_content and layout_weight dont wrk together  width="wrap_content" tells the UI to ignore weights for width.

Comment: @NidhinPrathap Width should be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> Other than TableLayout, is there anyother option to get desired
>   result?

Use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvQty"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:toLeftOf="@id/tvFoodPrice"
        android:toRightOf="@id/tvQty"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvFoodPrice"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can then add padding, margin and gravity to get actually what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp"
android:weightSum="6"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvQty"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
    android:text="x1"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvFoodName"
     android:layout_weight="4"
    android:text="Ceaser Salad with Herb Grilled Chicken Ceaser Ceaser Salad with Herb "
    android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvFoodPrice"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="1234"
    android:textColor="@color/baseDark"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```